# sound/soc/codec i2c driver won't probe

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing an audio codec in `sound/soc/codecs`.  It compiles and the init function calls, but the `probe()` function does not call.
I tried this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014627/probe-problem-when-writing-a-i2c-device-driver) advices, but no success.

I have also tried switching to the `sgtl5000.c` codec and including it in my `I2C_BOARD_INFO`in my boardfile, just to see if the `probe()` function will call, and that does not either.

```
static struct i2c_board_info mxc_i2c0_board_info[] __initdata = {
    {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("sgtl5000", 0x14),
    },
};
```

---

```
static const struct i2c_device_id sgtl5000_id[] = {
    {"sgtl5000", 0},
    {},
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, sgtl5000_id);

static struct i2c_driver sgtl5000_i2c_driver = {
    .driver = {
               .name = "sgtl5000",
               .owner = THIS_MODULE,
               },
    .probe = sgtl5000_i2c_probe,
    .remove = __devexit_p(sgtl5000_i2c_remove),
    .id_table = sgtl5000_id,
};
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: There should be a MACHINE_START(...) in your board file.  It will instantiate your machine, which will enumerate resources, which will eventually invoke your I2C probe.  For an example, take a look at: https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/arch/arm/mach-msm/board-msm8x60.c?id=refs/heads/android-msm-2.6.32

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes I do have MACHINE_START(...).  Another I2C driver (ov5640_mipi.c) can have its probe() called if I add its I2C_BOARD_INFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I am using the 'sabresd' boardfile.  This code segment from `mx6_sabresd_board_init` was overriding the first element of `mxc_i2c0_board_info`:

```
if (board_is_mx6_reva()) {
            strcpy(mxc_i2c0_board_info[0].type, "wm8958");
            mxc_i2c0_board_info[0].platform_data = &wm8958_config_data;
    } else {
            strcpy(mxc_i2c0_board_info[0].type, "wm8962");
            mxc_i2c0_board_info[0].platform_data = &wm8962_config_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you registering your i2c_device using something like "i2c_register_board_info" in your board file.( I could not comment on this question directly as it requires 50 reputations to have that privilege so the only option I had was answering this question to share my view).

Comment: Yes!  I'm using i2c_register_board_info for each i2c bus (0 to 2).